# String interpolation with an array

Tags: php

I am trying to create a link with php, but am having some difficulty.  Can someone help me with this.  I want the link to go to yourteam.php with the title being whatever the variable $row['User_ID'] is....

```
echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#D1D1D1\"><td>" . "<a href=\"yourteam.php\">$row['User_ID']</a>" . "</td><td><b>" . $row['Correct_Picks'] . " </b> /" . $maxcorrectpicks . "</td><td>" . $row['Points'] . "</td></tr>";
```

Comment: What is the html output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a array item in a double quoted string you leave out any quotes

```
echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#D1D1D1\"><td>" . "<a href=\"yourteam.php\">$row[User_ID]</a>" .
```

you can also wrap the variable in `{}`

```
echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#D1D1D1\"><td>" . "<a href=\"yourteam.php\">{$row['User_ID']}</a>" .
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo "<tr bgcolor='#D1D1D1'><td><a href='yourteam.php'>".$row['User_ID']."</a></td><td><b>" . $row['Correct_Picks'] . "</b>" . $maxcorrectpicks . "</td><td>" . $row['Points'] . "</td></tr>";
```

I suggest you to use `<strong></strong>` instead of `<b></b>` and also you can use inline style as `style='background-color:#D1D1D1;'` instead of `bgcolor`.

Answer (score 0):

I know people suggested using single quotes, but I like to use double quotes on my HTML attributes and use indentation within my echo statements for readibility. Here's how I would do it...

```
echo "<tr bgcolor=\"#D1D1D1\">";
echo "    <td><a href=\"yourteam.php\">{$row['User_ID']}</a></td>";
echo "    <td><b>{$row['Correct_Picks']}</b>{$maxcorrectpicks}</td>";
echo "    <td>{$row['Points']}</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```